# Как сделать отступ первого слова в абзаце TextView?

Tags: android

```
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
```

Так сдвигается весь абзац, а мне нужно только первое слово сдвинуть. То есть мне нужно сделать "красную строку".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

\t, в начале текста. Это управляющий символ, и при отображении строки он будет заменен 4мя пробелами. Наверняка вы сталкивались с \n - переходом на новую строку.

Comment: Спасибо - работает)